# How to include cck field image in Forward module template (forward.tpl.php)

Tags: 7, theming, entities

I'm using the Forward module and need help adding a custom field into the forward.tpl.php template.  I've found a similar thread on d.o:
https://drupal.org/node/2078479

However, this is for using user profile fields, not node fields.  Here is the code that I came up with, but it's not fully working:

```
<?php
$path = drupal_get_normal_path($_GET["path"]);
$path = explode("/", $path);
$nid = $path[1];
$forwardthumb = node_load($nid);
$img_uri = $forwardthumb->field_thumb['und'][0]['uri'];
$fid = $forwardthumb->field_thumb['und'][0]['fid'];
$thumbfilename = file_load($fid)->filename;
$derivative_uri = image_style_path($style, $image_uri);
$success = file_exists($derivative_uri) || image_style_create_derivative($style, $image_uri, $derivative_uri);
$new_image_url  = file_create_url($derivative_uri);
?>
```

In my testing, I've gotten the following text to output in my forwarded-email:
http://mysite.com/sites/default/files/styles/blog_thumb/public

(from the $new_image_url variable)

Which tells me that I've got it *partially* working, as it was able to indicate the correct folder / location... but I was never able to actually get it to spit out my image-file-name (e.g. thumbnail.png), just the path to the folder containing my image. Please let me know what I'm doing wrong?

Seems like part of this is a bit wonky, as it seems the $node variable in the template isn't the same $node variable used elsewhere in Drupal...?

[Edit] Wanted to also share the code that WORKS in a node.tpl file, but not in forward.tpl:

```
<img src="<?php print file_create_url($node->field_main_blog_image['und'][0]['uri']); ?>" />
```

But, when I set this code up in forward.tpl:

```
$path = drupal_get_normal_path($_GET["path"]);
$path = explode("/", $path);
$nid = $path[1];
$forwardthumb = node_load($nid);
```

And:

```
<img src="<?php print file_create_url($forwardthumb->field_main_blog_image['und'][0]['uri']); ?>" />
```

No luck...

Answer (score 0):

Posted my solution on Drupal's site, the forward module issue queue:

https://drupal.org/node/2107769

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.